# variables that I only define and they change their values as the program progresses?

Tags: python, variables

I am trying to build to sudoku solver. To check if the board is solved, I need the sum of all rows, columns and boxes. This is what I am doing.

```
class puzzle():
    def __init__(self,puzzle):
        self.board = puzzle[:]    ## puzzle is of the form [[(row1)],[(row2)],[(row3)],...,[(row9)]]

        self.sumr1 = sum(i for i in self.board[0])
        ## and the sums of the other rows.
        ## Similar for columns and boxes.
```

But this only makes the variables have the values that the board initially gave them. I don't want to manually update their values whenever I find a digit and put it in its place.

I am looking for something like view objects in dictionaries. They update in real time without manual intervention. Please guide me.

Comment: You've got to write a function that counts the sum, and call it after every move.

Comment: @DYZ That is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: That's unavoidable.

Comment: @DYZ Okay then. I think I will just make a function to update them then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check if the puzzle is solved, and use the returned value to decide what to do:

You must check rows, the columns and the 9 3x3 blocks; I don't think the sum of rows is enough

```
class puzzle():
    def __init__(self, puzzle):
        self.board = [row[:] for row in puzzle]    

    def is_solved(self)-> bool:
        compare_to = list(range(10))
        is_solved = True
        for row in self.board:
            is_solved = is_solved  and (sorted(row) == compare_to)
            if not is_solved:
                return False
        for idx in range(10):
            column = [row[idx] for row in self.board]
            is_solved = is_solved and (sorted(column) == compare_to)
            if not is_solved:
                return False

        # check the blocks here

        return is_solved
```